# Laurent expansion for $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, power-series, laurent-series

Let $f(z) = \sqrt{z(z-1)}$. The branch cut is the real interval $[0,1]$, and $f(z)>0$ for real $z$ that are greater than 1. I need to find the first few terms of the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ for $\left|z\right| > 1$ (centered at zero). I also need the radius of convergence.

I don't really know where to start for this one. I tried rewriting as $f(z) = z\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{z}}$, as some have suggested, but this doesn't appear that enlightening.

This is a study question when reviewing for a qualifying exam.

Comment: Now use the binomial theorem $(1-z^{-1})^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}(-1)^kz^{-z}$.

Comment: This works! Thanks! But how do I find the radius of convergence? Is it as simple as $\left|z\right| > 1$?

Comment: I used the information from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Convergent_Laurent_series) to answer the second part of the question. I may write up an answer to my own question if I get the time.